# Asking a question about material in poker book

Tags: discussion

I have a question that came directly from a poker book. To be precise the reasoning and how the writer came to a solution. So I can't 'mask it' using simple 'villain' and 'hero'.

The question is, can I ask it, or it's considered as plagiarism?

Answer (score 2):

By [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plagiarism?s=t), plagiarism is:

> plagiarism = an act or instance of using or closely imitating the language and thoughts of another author without authorization and **the representation of that author's work as one's own, as by not crediting the original author**.

I'm faaar from being an expert on this, but I think that, as long as you clearly mention the book where you took it from, the definition of plagiarism will not apply.

Also, I'm pretty sure that you won't have copyright problems either. Let's be real: no one is going to sue some random guy on the Internet for copying a paragraph from a book. Those copyright laws are for catching much much bigger fish.

If I were you, I would ask the question.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Crediting the author and source would likely benefit them and Poker.SE. After all, building a discussion around their material is something authors undoubtedly want. If you have broader questions that relate to the material you post, id be inclined to add those in some form as well.